# Using a loop to read, clean, and write, multiple .csv's in r

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple (~ 80) .csv's in a common folder that I need to subset certain columns and write the subset-ed new table into a new .csv. I have a script that I can use to do them one at a time:

```
setwd("C:/Data/HAAS")

### ENTER COUNTY NAME

county.name <- "charlotte"


####ENTER UNZIPPED CSV DOWNLOADED FROM ftp://sdrftp03.dor.state.fl.us/Tax%20Roll%20Data%20Files/2016%20Final%20NAL%20-%20SDF%20Files/


cnty.raw<- read.csv("C:/Data/HAAS/tax_roll_data/NAL18F201601.csv")
cnty.clean <- ""                                    ## CREATE NEW EMPTY DATAFRAME


cnty.clean$CNTY_ID <- cnty.raw$CO_NO                ## ADD COUNTY ID TO CLEAN FILE
cnty.clean$PARCEL_ID <- cnty.raw$PARCEL_ID          ## ADD PARCEL ID TO CLEAN FILE 
cnty.clean$ACT_BUILT <- cnty.raw$ACT_YR_BLT         ## ADD ACTUAL YEAR BUILT TO CLEAN FILE
cnty.clean$FLUCCS <- cnty.raw$DOR_UC                ## ADD LAND USE COLUMN
cnty.clean$HMSTD_VAL <- cnty.raw$AV_HMSTD           ## USED TO DETERMINE IF PARCEL CONTAINS A HOMESTEAD

cnty.clean <- cnty.clean[cnty.clean$FLUCCS == 001, ]   ## SELECT ONLY SINGLE-FAMILY RESIDENTIAL PROPERTIES 
cnty.clean <- na.omit(cnty.clean)                      ## REMOVE NA VALUES
head(cnty.clean)


#### BEGIN WRITING CLEANED TABLES TO OUTPUT FOLDERS ##################################

setwd("C:/Data/HAAS/R_output/csv")                    ## CSV DESTINATION FOLDER


write.csv(cnty.clean, file = paste(county.name, ".csv", sep = ""))    ## WRITE CSV TO FOLDER

setwd("C:/Data/HAAS/R_output/dbf")                                    ## DBF DESTINATION FOLDER
library(foreign)

write.dbf(cnty.clean, file = paste(county.name, ".dbf", sep = ""))    ## WRITE AS .DBF FOR SHAPEFILE MERGE

#### RESET WORKING DIRECTORY BACK TO ORIGINAL PATH

setwd("C:/Data/HAAS")

head(cnty.clean)
summary(cnty.clean)
```

the problem is that I have to manualy change the csv file name and also the county name field manually everytime I want to run the code through all of the csv's.

I have used r to do simple tasks, but am an amateur when it comes to automating processes using loops. Is there a way I can insert this code into a loop to run over and over again through all the csv's in the filepath's folder?

NOTE: I have searched around and tried different options in other posts, but none seem to work for my situation.

Comment: have a look at the `list.files` function.  This will list all the files in a specified directory. You can assign the result to a variable and then loop over that variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the file names using `list.files`.  The option `full.names = TRUE` gives you the full path of the file name, instead of relational.  Here's a simple example that should be extensible.

```
dfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)

county.names <- #vector of counties

for(j in 1:length(county.names)){
   for (i in 1:length(dfiles)){
      #operations go here

       write.csv(cnty.clean, file = paste(county.names[j], ".csv", sep = "")))
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the county name issue. OP is going to need a table with files and associated county names.

Comment: @Bishops_Guest you're right, you could do it in one shot with a nested loop, however it wouldn't be computationally efficient.  I edited answer to show the concept.

Comment: Or have a lookup table linking csv file names with county names.

Comment: Your edit breaks it. This will make a huge number of extra and incorrect files since there will be one for each possible county and file pair. Each file corresponds to just one country. The look up table is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your csv files have the same column names you can do this:

```
library(foreign)
setwd("C:/Data/HAAS")
my_func <- function(path, county.name){
  cnty.raw <- read.csv(path)
  cnty.clean <- data.frame()

  cnty.clean$CNTY_ID <- cnty.raw$CO_NO                ## ADD COUNTY ID TO CLEAN FILE
  cnty.clean$PARCEL_ID <- cnty.raw$PARCEL_ID          ## ADD PARCEL ID TO CLEAN FILE 
  cnty.clean$ACT_BUILT <- cnty.raw$ACT_YR_BLT         ## ADD ACTUAL YEAR BUILT TO CLEAN FILE
  cnty.clean$FLUCCS <- cnty.raw$DOR_UC                ## ADD LAND USE COLUMN
  cnty.clean$HMSTD_VAL <- cnty.raw$AV_HMSTD           ## USED TO DETERMINE IF PARCEL CONTAINS A HOMESTEAD

  cnty.clean <- cnty.clean[cnty.clean$FLUCCS == 001, ]   ## SELECT ONLY SINGLE-FAMILY RESIDENTIAL PROPERTIES 
  cnty.clean <- na.omit(cnty.clean)                      ## REMOVE NA VALUES

  write.csv(cnty.clean, file = paste("R_output/csv/", county.name, ".csv", sep = ""))
  write.csv(cnty.clean, file = paste("R_output/dbf/", county.name, ".csv", sep = ""))

}

list_path <- c("tax_roll_data/NAL18F201601.csv", "path/to/second/file.csv")
list_county <- c("charlotte", "second county")

mapply(my_func, path = list_path, county.name = list_county)
```

**NOTE:** This changes your file paths to relative paths so you can leave out the `"C:/Data/HAAS/"` portion in the list of paths.

You can use the `list.files` function described in the other answer to build your list of paths but this solution should run much faster than a for loop. This, however, does assume you have an equal number of county names and paths. Otherwise it will reuse values from the shorter of the two lists and give you unexpected (and unwanted) results

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`f <- list.files('C:/Data/HAAS/tax_roll_data', pattern='.csv')` to get the files in your folder C:/Data/HAAS/tax_roll_data into a vector. Then loop through `f`, something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(f)){ 
cnty.raw <- read.csv(f[i])

#Rest of your script
}
```